# Proof verification of $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_kq^k$ is Cauchy given $|a_k| \le C, |q| < 1, k\in\Bbb N$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$:
>   $$
> x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_kq^k
> $$ 
>   and:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> |a_k| \le C\\
> |q| < 1\\
> k\in\Bbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove $\{x_n\}$ is a fundamental sequence.

By definition of a fundamental sequence we want to show: $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$. So:
$$
\begin{align}
|x_n - x_m| &= \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_kq^k - \sum_{k=1}^m a_kq^k\right| \stackrel{m>n}{=} \\
&= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_kq^k \right| \le \\ 
&\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m \left|a_kq^k \right| \le \\ &\le \sum_{k=n+1}^m \left|Cq^k \right| \stackrel{\text{geom. sum}}{=} \frac{Cq(q^m - q^n)}{q-1}
\end{align}
$$

Let $m > n$:
$$
\frac{Cq(q^m - q^n)}{q-1} = \frac{Cq(q^n - q^m)}{1-q} \le \frac{Cq^{n+1}}{1-q}
$$
Let $q$:
$$
q = \frac{1}{1+r},\ r \in \Bbb R_{>0}
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{Cq^{n+1}}{1-q} = \frac{Cq}{(1-q)(1+r)^{n}} \stackrel{n > N}{\le} \frac{Cq}{(1-q)(1+r)^{N}} < \epsilon
$$
Finally:
$$
\frac{Cq}{(1-q)(1+r)^{N}} < \epsilon \iff (1+r)^{N} > \frac{Cq}{(1-q)\epsilon} \\
\iff N > \log_{1+r} \frac{Cq}{(1-q)\epsilon} \implies |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon
$$

I'm kindly asking to verify the proof above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done.

If I want to nitpick, a very minor issue is that it is possible that $q$ can be negative. Hence, making this statement false.$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m \left|Cq^k \right| \stackrel{\text{geom. sum}}{=} \frac{Cq(q^m - q^n)}{q-1}$$

A quick fix is just to change $q$ to $|q|$.

Comment: indeed, you are right! thanks for the notice